# Colloquial English word for: a "Remote control"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, british-english, colloquialisms

What is the most popular word used for calling: "Remote control" in British families?

How do the people call it? How the children call it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just some clarifications, if you will: are you looking for some sort of statistical data indicating what is the *most* popular word used for a TV remote control, or are you simply looking for a very common term that would be accepted without a raised eyebrow by the average British listener?

Comment: "Clicker" is incredibly common, everywhere, all English-speaking regions..

Comment: Yep, "clicker", though possibly only in older people who remember when they clicked.

Comment: @Avner Shahar The sec option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [remote](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remote): (both BrE and AmE)

> - A remote control device.

[Clicker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clicker) but mainly in AmE:

> - A remote control, as for a television or DVD player. (AHD)

The Free Dictionary

- Here is a list of slang words for the remote control:

> - What do you call your remote control [remote control](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/what-you-call-your-remote-3198601)?
> - Linguists have studied hundreds of newly invented slang words which are now in every day use - and have found 57 words for a remote control.
>     And the experts put the prevalence of slang down to what they call 'the global domination of the English language'.
> - Experts have found that slang is flourishing across all social groups, including words for a remote control ***such as blabber, zapper, melly and dawicki.***

Comment: For what it's worth, I think *remote* is also the most common in the U.S. (I haven't heard *clicker* used very often in real life, though there may be regional differences or something.)

Comment: I didn't mean to say that in U.S. remote is not used,

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't think you did. :-)

Comment: *Clicker* is rare. These days it's more likely to refer to a remote control for giving power point presentations. *Zapper* used to be common but *remote* is probably more common now. (Southern England)

Comment: Remote, as I said, is the term commonly used. Other options are less common. TV remote vs TV clicker vs TV zapper: (AmE) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=TV+clicker%2CTV+remote+control%2C+TV++zapper&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTV%20clicker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTV%20remote%20control%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTV%20zapper%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ngrams have little or no relationship to spoken English

Comment: @JoeBlow _ I added it in a comment, not in the answer, and despite its limits I think it reflects usage in this case.

Comment: 'Clicker' was common in the 1970s and early 80s, when TV and cable remotes had switches and larger buttons that actually made clicking noises.

Comment: If I recall, the word I most often heard in the the 70s was **“clacker”**, not “clicker.” Pre-IR remotes used little tuning forks whose sounds were detected by the set, and the buttons would make a definite clacking sound.